# How to detect if a number belongs to a sequence in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sequence of numbers starting with 6 and then increasing by 60: `6, 66, 126, 186, ...`

How can I know if a number I input belongs to this sequence, and indicate that in some way, such as writing "true" on column B?

Comment: @fixer1234 oh wait ill try to explain it thoroughly ny editing the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `MOD(A,B)`, which returns the rest of the division of `A` by `B`:

```
=MOD(A1-6, 60)
```

If the number in `A1` is part of the sequence, it will return 0.

If you want a TRUE/FALSE instead:

```
=(MOD(A1-6, 60)=0)
```

Comment: This answer could be made even better by including some sample data and the corresponding results of your formula as a demonstration.